# "async with" if the event loop is running but no event loop

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I receive the following error when trying to run this basic code provided by the [Telethon documentation](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/get_full_channel.html). I'm confused as to why as I haven't established a loop.

> RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")

I am using python 3.7.7 in spyder 4.0.1

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

def channel_info(username, api_id, api_hash):
    with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash,channel) as client:
        result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
            channel=channel
        ))
        return(result)

out = channel_info(username, api_id, api_hash)
```

Comment: *> as I haven't established a loop*. By default, `asyncio` creates an event loop on the main thread, and tools like Anaconda/Spyder/IPython run said loop automatically for you, which enables you to use `async with`, `async for` and `await` directly in the interpreter.

Comment: It is a very important point. If you are the developer of the package explicitly mention it in the package documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [FAQ section](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#can-i-use-anaconda-spyder-ipython-with-the-library) of telethon's docs.

> **Can I use Anaconda/Spyder/IPython with the library?**
>
> Yes, but these
> interpreters run the asyncio event loop implicitly, which interferes
> with the telethon.sync magic module. If you use them, you should not
> import sync.

So avoid using the `sync` module.

You could try doing something like this instead:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions, types
from asyncio import run

API_ID= ...
API_HASH=" ... "

async def channel_info(username, api_id, api_hash):
    async with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = await client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
            channel=username
        ))
        return(result)


out = run(channel_info('durov', API_ID, API_HASH))
print(out)
```

Comment: I have tried your code in spyder. But it gives this error: `"asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Comment: @jonny789 same error for me. did u find the right way ?

Comment: @Ehsan, I don't run in spyder's Ipython console.  I run in a dedicated console. Go to `Run` > `Configuration per file` > Select `Execute in a dedicated console` under `Console`.